# How to produce a scatterplot in Julia-lang with labelled points?

Tags: plot, label, julia, scatter-plot

Using Julia-lang, how can a scatterplot of two vectors be plotted with `pyplots` (or GR) to label each point with a specific string? Eg. each paired (x,y) takes on the index value they both share? Example from MATLAB: [image example](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/46891/versions/8/screenshot.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean with GR or PyPlot themselves, or through Plots.jl? I know Plots.jl best - with that you'd do `scatter(x,y, series_annotations = text.(1:length(x), :bottom))` .
Unfortunately it currently plots very close to the points - `:bottom` means that the bottom of the text touches the point.

Comment: thank you for your response, could you assist me with an error I receive? `ERROR: TypeError: getfield: expected Symbol, got UnitRange{Int64}`

Comment: I did fix that part with a temp vector ` ["1","2","3","4","5"]` which works, but the function syntax looks good and need to figure out what it does/how it operates. (I thought that Plots.jl was the backend for GR/PyPlot)

Comment: Are you on Julia-0.5? The syntax assumes 0.6

Comment: I am on 0.4.5. I believe that I did the updates to be on the most recent version, unless there is a way to skip to a future version? (btw, saw your github contributions on the Plot libraries which are look stunning!)

Comment: to make the string array I use a list comprehension `[string(x) for x in 1:NN]` and works fine. There are a lot of things to learn in the julia plotting facilities

Comment: Thanks! To be on the current version of julia you need to download a new binary from here https://julialang.org/downloads/ - (even if you're on Linux and are used to updates coming automatically)